# Adding html dashboard themes for the wordpress admin area

Tags: themes, dashboard, wp-admin

I want to start a wordpress multi site service, in order to customize the admin panel for customers, Is there any way to install html dashboard themes on wordpress admin area?
Thanks in advance for your answer;

Comment: What have you tried or researched?

Comment: Hello sir ; sorry I could not understand your question , but if you want to know about the dashboard theme, we want to use Gentellela which has built on bootstrap3 , I do not know ho to make it compatible with wordpress dashboard , thanks for your answer